# API Call only works on homepage but not subpage?

Tags: javascript, api

I'm relatively new working with promises in JS. I got the API call to work on the initial homepage, but I'm having issues when I go to another page that is using the same API call.

In my api.js file I have the following:

```
const key = apiKey;
const commentsUrl = axios.get(`https://project-1-api.herokuapp.com/comments/?api_key=${key}`);
const showsUrl = axios.get(`https://project-1-api.herokuapp.com/showdates?api_key=${key}`);

async function getData() {
    const allApis = [commentsUrl, showsUrl];

    try {
        const allData = await Promise.allSettled(allApis);

        return allData;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

In my index.html

```
import { getData } from "./api.js";

let data = await getData(); //This works and gathers the data from the API.
```

In my shows.html

```
import { getData } from "./api.js";

let showsData = await getData(); //This does not and says that cannot access commentsUrl (api.js) before it is initialized. But it is?
```

If I comment out the code from "show", the API GET request works fine and the index page loads the API data correctly. Can anyone explain to me what's happening and why I would be getting the uninitialized error?

I also should note that if I split the API calls onto two seperate two js files (one for the index, one for the shows), the API calls works and displays the data as it is intended to.

Comment: Gave that a shot but no dice.

Comment: Aren't you using those axios calls wrong? You should have a *function* that returns the promise, e.g. `var myApi = function() { return axios.get('...'); }`

Comment: @Flame I don't believe so? In my try block I have it as an array of API calls that will be all settled since I'm using the .allSettled([arrayOfAPIRequests]).

My files are calling the async function which then returns an object of arrays (one being for the index.html and the other for the shows.html)

It's only when I load shows.html that I get an error in console stating that the variable `commentsUrl` is not initialized and it cannot be accessed.

Comment: those `commentsUrl` and `showsUrl` variables execute immediately. Once the promise is resolved it can no longer be called. Hence my previous comment.

Comment: I figured out what was happening and it made sense as to why. I had a node race somewhere else in the file.

Comment: your code sample still looks wrong to me and I dont see any race condition. Those axios http requests execute immediately on including that `api.js` file. You dont even need to call `getData()` unless you need the response.